# How to insert into STL set?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm having problems and I'm not sure I understand the STL documentation. Let's say I have this:

```
#include <set>
...

struct foo
{
    int bar;
};

struct comp
{
    inline bool operator()(const foo& left,const foo& right)
    {
        return left.bar < right.bar;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<foo,comp> fooset;  // Uses comparison struct/class object comp to sort the container

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

How do I insert struct `foo`s into the `set` using my own comparator struct?

Comment: Did you try to use the `insert` method yet? What error did you get?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `set::insert` method, there is nothing more to do. For example,

```
foo f1, f2;
f1.bar = 10;
f2.bar = 20;

fooset.insert(f1);
fooset.insert(f2);
```

Comment: fooset.insert(foo); //

like that? and it'll be inserted in the correct position?

Comment: As I have shown in the example code, `fooset.insert(f1);`, while inserting `set` will use the comparison functor provided by you to determine the correct position for the object.

Comment: @JayKim If you're depending on the position of an element in a set (though well defined in the STL) to do something, you're probably using a wrong data structure.

Comment: @manasij - i thought using upper and lower bound from set would be a good way to do range searches? no?

Comment: Any solution based on `std::operator[]` ?

Comment: @SohailSi there is no such operator for `std::set`.